# Creating a password protected and not removeable file in java

Tags: java, zip, aes

I want to create a pasword secured encripted file. But it should not be able to delete or move without knowing password. How can I do this using java. I have already know how encrypt. I just want to know how that encrypted password protecte file is secured by others without damaging the file.I am using windows 7.

Comment: Files are more related to file system and file system on OS. Mention which OS you are working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment earlier, it's based on the OS you are using.

Through java you can create a file and can set permissions to the file.

You can protect your file from other users by giving read only or no permission to the file for them. But an administrator or the file owner can always delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Moving and deleting a file has nothing to do with Java or encryption. This is a function of the File System. You might be able to partially achieve this in a file system that allows encryption (eg: you can hide the existence of the file by encrypting the parent directory - as long as the file system also encrypts the metadata) but ultimately the file will still be deletable.

In short: in general, you can't